# Anything wrong with this question about monads?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Here's [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704652/monad-in-plain-english-for-the-oop-programmer-with-no-fp-background-closed) about "Monads in plain English".

Currently, the question is 20% the question itself and 80% explanations why it's not a dupe.

I pretty much stated my position in comments there (perhaps, in a more aggressive manner than I should -- my comment even was deleted).  My position is that the question is a dupe and an only its consequence is scattering good answers to same question between several pages.

However, I'm pretty much in doubt what should be done there.  The situation is that the question, otherwise closed and abandoned, had suddenly gotten an outstanding answer.  What should be done there?

Comment: @fig, you can post whatever you want.  But in case you really want my approval: okay, I approve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now that the question has an outstanding answer we should let it stick around, but of course it could still be closed and stick around and be voted on.  The only problem is that once it's closed then it could be deleted, and that would be tragic.

So now that we're at this point, I would keep to open.

**We don't want to lose good answers.** [While I don't have time to absorb the answer right now, I plan on going back and studying it, until I get it.]

Comment: There is no need to "lose" the answer - the answerer just has to post it to the original question.

Comment: @Neil, it certainly wouldn't be right to have him lose all the rep he deserves from that answer, and as of yet there is no answer migration capability that preserves the upvotes.

Comment: @Lance I'm not so interested in his rep as in preserving the question - posting it to the original (i.e. non-dupe)  question will do that.

Comment: Hm, why would anyone want to delete this question if it's closed?  Deleting doesn't happen automatically.  And, by the way, if *someone* wasn't so hard defending his question, there wouldn't be any rep problem.

Comment: @Lance I meant of course "preserving the answer" - for some reason I can never get this right, I suppose I should use the catch-all "content".

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about monads (there *is* a hazy memory but it's from... biology class?) so I can't judge the dupe-ness of the question, but if it is a dupe, maybe it's an idea to ask the author of the outstanding answer (impressive, by the looks of it!) to migrate it to the original question?

Comment: Only place I've come across monads elsewhere is in philosophy.

Comment: @Neil seems to be a german-only word for a single-cell organism.

Answer (score -1):

I wasn't so blown away by the answer, but the answerer can always post it to the question that the one you refer to is a dupe of.

Comment: Its hard to be blown away when Eric Lippert writes so many fantastic answers.

Comment: @Chaos Well, verbose ones.